# Keep the first day of the month, even when it is repeated in R

Tags: r, date

Suppose that you have data like the following, in which, as you can see, the first day of the month is repeated more than once (**note** the `date` variable).

```
    date     exdate strike_price     delta
1: 1996-01-04 1997-06-21       500000 -0.094917
2: 1996-01-04 1996-03-16       600000  0.768930
3: 1996-01-04 1996-02-17       605000 -0.286091
4: 1996-01-04 1996-12-21       600000  0.651049
5: 1996-01-04 1996-03-16       540000 -0.040929
6: 1996-01-04 1996-02-17       630000 -0.638877
7: 1996-01-05 1996-02-17       440000  0.579155
.....
51: 1996-02-04 1997-06-21       500000 -0.094917
52: 1996-02-04 1996-03-16       600000  0.768930
53: 1996-02-04 1996-02-17       605000 -0.286091
54: 1996-02-04 1996-12-21       600000  0.651049
55: 1996-02-04 1996-03-16       540000 -0.040929
56: 1996-02-04 1996-02-17       630000 -0.638877
```

1. What I try to do is, for each month, to keep ALL the first days of observations, i.e. all the observations from `1:6` in the set, based on the `date` variable. Simply put; the first day of each month is present more than once, and I want to keep all of them, while disregarding the rest days of the month.
2. Is it then possible to choose from the remaining observations the ones that have the first two earliest `expdate` based after the changes done in step 1 ?

The date format is `YYYY-mm-dd`.

So far I manage to keep only one of the first days of the month, instead of all of those days. The code i use is this, but it doesn't return the desired result:

```
setDT(df)[order(date), .(delta[which.min(date)], date[which.min(date)]), by = .(year(date), month(date))]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your date variable of class Date? You can use `str(dt)` to check and `dt[, date := as.Date(date)]` to convert it conditional on it being in the format in your example. If this is not the issue, then you should produce a dataset that can reproduce the issue that you mention in an example data set, maybe `dput(head(dt, 20))` and see that the issue is repeated there. The answer I provided works properly on the example data.

Comment: everything is `as.Date`. The thing is, because i have hundreds of different dates, the ordering by: `rank(exdate) < 3` considers the rank of ALL exdates of the dateset, and not per "group" of dates.

Comment: Again, that is only true without the `by=argument`. In `dtNew[, .I[rank(exdate) < 3], by=date]`, `rank(exdate)` calculates the rank for each date separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely a more efficient answer, but this works:

```
# if data table is not loaded
library(data.table)
# if dt is a data.frame
setDT(dt)
```

Then the following code will produce what you want.

```
dt[dt[, .(date=min(date)), by=.(month(date), year(date))][,.(date)], on="date"]
```

The idea is to get join the original data.table onto a data.table with a single column containing the minimum date for each month. The i argument to the data.table is a chained data.table where the first link in the chain returns a three column data.table with the minimum date by month and year and the second link in the chain drops the month and year variables to only return the date variable. This data.table is joined onto the original data.table using the `on="date"` argument.

This returns

```
          date     exdate strike_price     delta
 1: 1996-01-04 1997-06-21       500000 -0.094917
 2: 1996-01-04 1996-03-16       600000  0.768930
 3: 1996-01-04 1996-02-17       605000 -0.286091
 4: 1996-01-04 1996-12-21       600000  0.651049
 5: 1996-01-04 1996-03-16       540000 -0.040929
 6: 1996-01-04 1996-02-17       630000 -0.638877
 7: 1996-02-04 1997-06-21       500000 -0.094917
 8: 1996-02-04 1996-03-16       600000  0.768930
 9: 1996-02-04 1996-02-17       605000 -0.286091
10: 1996-02-04 1996-12-21       600000  0.651049
11: 1996-02-04 1996-03-16       540000 -0.040929
12: 1996-02-04 1996-02-17       630000 -0.638877
```

---

for the second step, the two lowest exdates among the remaining (by date), you could do this in two lines.

```
# save above data.table
dtNew <- dt[dt[, .(date=min(date)), by=.(month(date), year(date))][,.(date)], on="date"]
# merge on the rows of the data.table that have the two lowest exdates
dtNew[dtNew[, .I[rank(exdate) < 3], by=date]$V1,]
```

.I is used to return the row number of the original data.table (dtNew) and rank is used to calculated the rankings.

**data**

```
dt <- 
structure(list(date = structure(c(9499, 9499, 9499, 9499, 9499, 
9499, 9500, 9530, 9530, 9530, 9530, 9530, 9530), class = "Date"), 
    exdate = c("1997-06-21", "1996-03-16", "1996-02-17", "1996-12-21", 
    "1996-03-16", "1996-02-17", "1996-02-17", "1997-06-21", "1996-03-16", 
    "1996-02-17", "1996-12-21", "1996-03-16", "1996-02-17"), 
    strike_price = c(500000L, 600000L, 605000L, 600000L, 540000L, 
    630000L, 440000L, 500000L, 600000L, 605000L, 600000L, 540000L, 
    630000L), delta = c(-0.094917, 0.76893, -0.286091, 0.651049, 
    -0.040929, -0.638877, 0.579155, -0.094917, 0.76893, -0.286091, 
    0.651049, -0.040929, -0.638877)), .Names = c("date", "exdate", 
"strike_price", "delta"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), index = structure(integer(0), "`\`__date\``" = integer(0)))
```

Comment: I was thinking something like it yes! Thank you.
Have you considered the 2nd part of question which is slightly more tricky?

Comment: Could you please explain me the part at the end: ' on="date" ' because it gives an error of unused argument

Comment: It is weird; even though i updated it i get the same unused argument error.
`newdata<-DF[DF[, .(date=min(date)), by=.(month(date), year(date))][,.(date)], on="date"]`

Comment: ah it makes sense now. I did find another way in the meantime ( longer in code) which yielded the same result! Awesome. Thank you.

Do you have any ideas for the 2nd step?

Comment: and that `$V1` ?

Comment: V1 is the default variable name that data.table produces when a name is not explicitly provided. Here, V1 is the row numbers that fit the logical comparison. `$V1` pulls this out as a vector to feed into the `i` argument of the data.table.

Comment: Hmm from examining the part 2 : The code yields the min 2 dates throughout the dataset; not the min for each month of step 1.

Comment: It returns the first two exdates for each date included in dtNew.

Comment: I know that this is what it is supposed to be, but my dataset is 343903 obs long, and each 1st day of the month having 200 approx entries. But doing this, the final dataset is 3 obs long. :/